# How does the UA Sharpshooter fighter's Snap Shot feature interact with Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, fighter, unearthed-arcana

In an [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/2016_Fighter_UA_1205_1.pdf), there is a fighter archetype: Sharpshooter.

At level 18, they gain the following ability:

> **Snap Shot**
>
> Starting at 18th level, if you take the Attack action on your first turn of a combat, you can make one additional ranged weapon attack as part of that action.

How does Snap Shot interact with the fighter's existing Extra Attack feature?

For example, at level 18, the fighter has Extra Attack (2); would my first Attack action look like:

normal attack + extra attack + extra attack + snap shot?

or is it:

normal attack + snap shot + extra attack + snap shot + extra attack + snap shot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You gain one additional attack roll, per Attack action used*

*During the first round of combat.

A level 18 fighter, as you mentioned, has Extra Attack (2). Normally, they would make three attacks with their Attack action. With Snap Shot, they are able to make an additional, fourth attack. So, to recreate your question formatting:

> First round Attack action
>    = Attack + Extra Attack + Extra Attack + Snap Shot

---

#### Some things to keep in mind

- At level 20, fighters gain Extra Attack (3). This would bring your total attacks per Attack action in the first round up to five.
- When you use an Action Surge and use it to attack, that counts as an Attack action and would trigger the Snap Shot bonus.
- If you happen to have *haste* cast on you, you gain an additional action, which can be used to take the Attack action, with the caveat "one weapon attack only"; I would argue that this class feature (specific) adds to that spell ability (general), but your DM may disagree.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, by what logic do you interpret "one weapon attack only" as allowing more than one weapon attack?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I believe this to be a case where the class feature (specific) beats the spell limitation (general).

Comment: ah I see. Personally I would rule that the class feature is more specific but I can see how that would be unclear.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I would rule the same. The class feature says "all Attack actions now have +1 attack", while the *Haste* action says "this specific type of Attack action only has 1 attack". Therefore, *Haste* is more specific, because the class feature targets all Attack actions, but *Haste* doesn't.

Comment: Remember that 'extra attack' is also a class feature, so if your DM rules (as this answer suggests) that class features are a more specific scoping of the haste spell's text then you actually get all up-to-five attacks with haste, and 4 attacks extra with it whenever it isn't the first turn!

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I am suggesting that this particular class feature (snap shot) is more specific than the clause in the spell (haste), not that all class features are more specific than all spells, or even just the haste spell.

Comment: @goodguy5: I don't see why Snap Shot would necessarily be "more specific" than *haste* (and thus apply despite *haste*'s limitation) if Extra Attack isn't treated the same way.

Answer (score 7):

The Snap Shot feature description is referring to the **Attack action**, not to individual attacks. Regardless of the number of extra attacks you get *as part of* your Attack action, this does not change the number of Attack actions you take (1).

Abilities granting you additional actions - like *Action Surge* - could allow you to use the *Attack action* multiple times on your first turn, though, increasing the number of additional attacks.

Comment: This answer could benefit from a summary with how many attacks (dice rolls) can be taken in total.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one activation of Snap Shot since the activation condition is Attack **Action** and not attack.

Regarding the order each is activated, when you expend abilities, if the order is not specified in the ability, ***you* can decide which order abilities are expended**.

Both **Extra Attack** and **Snap Shot** have an activation condition of using an **Attack Action**.

Both become active when you use the Attack Action.  You can decide which order each activates.  Additionally, you can move before, after, or in-between any of the attacks.

This is important if you are mixing melee attacks and ranged attacks with Snap Shot (with say, a Hand Crossbow or thrown Dagger since Snap Shot *only permits a Ranged Attack*).  You may choose to change the order so you do not suffer Disadvantage for making a Ranged Attack while within 5 ft, or to stay within the rules for equipping/stowing weaponry.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already.